# How to escape an angular scope variable in a kiwi template

Tags: node.js, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, kiwi-template

I have a scope variable (`myVar`) which is defined in `MyController`:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = 'whatsoever';
}]);
```

I want to **use its value within my template** but I keep getting this error: *Unknown tag 'myVar'*. I think I need to escape `myVar` somehow:

```
<section ng-controller="MyController">
    <span class="{{myVar}}">{{myVar}}</span>
</section>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you give some code for how you initialize myVar and what value it contains? I mean your full MyController code.

Comment: try `$scope` instead of `scope`

Comment: where exactly are you seeing this error appear?

Comment: My Nodejs instance does not start due to the *Unknown tag `myVar'* error. I am using the kiwi template engine which may cause thiss error because of the curly brackets. That's why I think I have to escape those.

Comment: ok so you are trying to use a template engine that uses `{{ }}` to denote it's tags and want the template to ignore the elements as a tag and instead pass them through to angular?

Comment: @AndrewCounts yep, exactly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for kiwi templates at https://github.com/coolony/kiwi, the only mechanism that they provide for escaping out of their template mode is the `{{raw}} {{/raw}}` clause.  so you would probably accomplish what you want by doing the following:

```
{{raw}}<span class="{{myVar}}">{{myVar}}</span>{{/raw}}
```

That being said, I don't suspect this is a very good engine to use for templates with Angular.js compatibility, as the mixing of the use of the `{{ }}` operand between the two frameworks will make troubleshooting issues extremely laborious.

Answer (score 0):

You have not injected $scope into your controller. Also use $scope instead of scope. Like this...

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('ImagesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.didSelectLanguage=function($scope, $http) {
            console.log($scope);
            $http.jsonp('http://localhost:3000/image?quantity=1&language='+this.language+'&Flag=&callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
            .success(function(data){
            $scope.image = data;
            });

        }

  }])
```

Comment: sorry this was just a copy-paste mistake, edited in question code

Comment: Have you injected scope into controller?

Comment: but the answer is still not wrong, you are missing $scope in the parameters of your controller.

Comment: yes, I injected it, as I said it was just a mistake when creating the example code from my code

Comment: Agree, so you did not get any help in this I guess!

Comment: Defining the variable in my controller is not the problem. My Nodejs instance does not start due to the mistake described above.

Comment: The dependeny you have added should be in QUOTES. '$scope' instead of simply $scope. Beside your controller name, as I shown in my example code.

Comment: Thanks for your remarks but the controller is not the problem. It is my template which is not being rendered.

Comment: Lastly, try logging scope in your controller, console.log($scope);

Comment: As I said, defining `myVar` is working well, I can log it's value without any problems

Comment: Have you injected .js containing MyController into the HTML file you are refering to?